# Repeat the "if" statement if it has to go to the "else" statement

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop

int type = 0, num = 0, square, cube;

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Press 1 to Square a Number\nPress 2 to Cube a Number ");
    type = input.nextInt();

    if (type == 1)
    {
            do
        {
            System.out.println("Type a number to square ");
            num = input.nextInt();
            square = num * num;
            System.out.println(square);
        }
        while (num != 0);   
    }

    else if (type == 2)
    {
        do
        {
            System.out.println("Type a number to cube ");
            num = input.nextInt();
            cube = num * num * num;
            System.out.println(cube);
        }
        while (num != 0);   
    }

    else 
        System.out.println("Please type either 1 or 2");

        ----> here I want it to go back to the top and ask again.
        ----> how do it do this part?
```

Read right above this where I put in those arrows. That's the part I need help with.

(dont mind this. this thing just kept prompting me to put more normal words in it
so this is what I'm doing)

```
}
```

Comment: You want a `while` loop

Comment: If it wanted you to keep putting more normal words, there's probably a reason. They didn't just put the minimum word limit in there for kicks, so don't fluff your post to circumvent it.

Comment: wow. thanks Matt, you're helpful... and the person Aditya was right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the whole code block in a while loop
with
`while((type!=1 && type!=2))
{
...
}`

this will do the trick

Comment: Thanks man. I put everything after the line where I made the Scanner into a "Do While" loop with the "while" part what you said and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ((type!=1) && (type!=2))
{
  if......
```